# Trigger an action when a certain string is found in the ouput of a process bash

Tags: bash

I'm monitoring the events generated from a camera using gphoto2.

An example output is this:

```
UNKNOWN PTP Event 400c, Param1 00010001
UNKNOWN PTP Event 400c, Param1 00010001
UNKNOWN PTP Event 400c, Param1 00010001
UNKNOWN PTP Event 2919, Param1 00000000
UNKNOWN PTP Event 400c, Param1 00010001
UNKNOWN PTP Event 400c, Param1 00010001
UNKNOWN PTP Event 2919, Param1 00000000
UNKNOWN PTP Event 400c, Param1 00010001
```

Being "Event 400c" when a new picture was taken(now know from trial an error), I would like to run a script when such string is found in the output (to download the image file and continue my process) while leaving monitor running for future events.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
tail -f data_file | while read l
  do 
   if [[ "$l" == *"Event 400c"* ]] 
   then 
        echo do something; 
   fi
done
```

Of course, you need to replace echo command by your command

Answer (score 0):

pipe it to grep and then pipe the input string to your script

Input stream:

```
$ cat temp
UNKNOWN PTP Event 400c,  Param1 00010001
UNKNOWN PTP Event 2919,  Param1 00000000
UNKNOWN PTP Event 400c,  Param1 00010001
UNKNOWN PTP Event 400c,  Param1 00010001
UNKNOWN PTP Event 2919,  Param1 00000000
UNKNOWN PTP Event 400c,  Param1 00010001
```

Some script to process data:

```
$ cat temp.py
#! /usr/bin/python
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    print "Input matching:", line,
```

Pipeline:

```
$ tail -f temp | grep 400c | python temp.py
Input matching: UNKNOWN PTP Event 400c,  Param1 00010001
Input matching: UNKNOWN PTP Event 400c,  Param1 00010001
Input matching: UNKNOWN PTP Event 400c,  Param1 00010001
Input matching: UNKNOWN PTP Event 400c,  Param1 00010001
```

Comment: I has been testing this solution but apparently grep (or maybe the pipe subsystem) waits for the first process to end in order to start working in the next process.

This doesnt work for monitoring, only for static output i'm afraid.

Comment: @Benjamin You need the `tail -f` bit to get a blocking read at EOF.

Comment: Ohh. I've just found out, hes using gphoto2, I accidentally thought hewas parsing some finished list of events. You are right. I've already changed.

Comment: Due to output buffering, using `grep` this way will likely not work as intended. If your `grep` version supports it (e.g., Linux, FreeBSD/OSX), use `--line-buffered` to ensure that matches are passed through _as they're encountered_; without it, you may end up waiting a loooong time - potentially infinitely - before `grep` passes any data to the Python script.